# Wordpress Google Cloud Launcher work just work with website.com/index.php/whatever

Tags: php, wordpress, virtual-machine, google-cloud-launcher

So after the deployment of Wordpress via the Google Cloud Launcher and the website is installed.

If i create a page for example: Contacts
This website is only accesible via website.com/index.php/contacts 
and not directly to website.com/contacts

My .htacces is as follow:

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.4.3]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My Permanlink is set to Post Name https://www.ccpalt.com.do/sample-post/

What else should I edit?